# Meaning of 'that's really the crab of my story'

Tags: meaning

> He made one or two other suggestions, but Scotland Yard had been before him in every case. That’s really the **crab** of my story, if you’ll excuse the expression.

From "Two Bottles of Relish" by Lord Dunsany.

What does "the crab" mean?

Comment: I thought I read an existing question similar to this a couple years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For fuller context, here is how the sentence containing *crab* comes up in [Dunsany's story](https://books.google.com/books?id=Y9aW_wykKc8C&pg=PT295&dq=%22He+made+one+or+two+other+suggestions,+but+Scotland+Yard+had+been+before+him+in+every+case%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cSCiVcjUEoW3ogSa05_4CQ&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22He%20made%20one%20or%20two%20other%20suggestions%2C%20but%20Scotland%20Yard%20had%20been%20before%20him%20in%20every%20case%22&f=false):

> "No," I says, "you're wrong there. Scotland Yard has been into that. And the Otherthorpe people before them. They've had a look at the drains, such as they are, a little thing running into a cesspool beyond the garden; and nothing has gone down it, nothing that oughtn't to have, I mean."
>
> He made one or two other suggestions, but Scotland Yard had been before him in every case. That's really the crab of my story, if you'll excuse the expression. You want a man who sets out to be a detective to take his magnifying glass and go down to the spot; to go to the spot before everything; and then to measure the footmarks and pick up the clues and find the knife that the police have overlooked. But Linley never even went near the place and he hadn't got a magnifying glass, not as I ever saw, and Scotland Yard were before him every time.

Dunsany wrote "Two Bottles of Relish" in 1932, [according to S.T. Joshi](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZH9b6axwqtYC&pg=PA159&lpg=PA159&dq=Dunsany+%22Two+bottles+of+relish%22&source=bl&ots=IKGray0s9g&sig=6-PF8g7C7r_sQCi2KwYp6RJSxq0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BiSiVemZB5C2ogT5i7xA&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=Dunsany%20%22Two%20bottles%20of%20relish%22&f=false), so any slang sense of *crab* that Dunsany may have been invoking would have to have been current during or before the 1930s.

Eric Partridge, *A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English* (1937) includes two senses of the noun *crab* that may be relevant:

> **crab.** ... —4. The action, or an instance of, finding fault : coll[oquial] : from ca. 1890. (O.E.D. Sup.) Ex *crab* v. ["To 'pull to pieces', criticize adversely"] —5. A drawback : coll[oquial] : from ca. 1910.

So it may be that *crab* is intended here to signify "the main criticism" or "the main shortcoming."

Comment: I'm guessing this is where the slightly dated adjective "crabby" to describe a fussy, critical individual came from.